# Conversion Tracking Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql, conversion, data-views

I have recently implemented conversion tracking in Marketing Cloud and I'm wondering if there's a way to capture the converted subscribers in a data extension with exporting from tracking and re importing them into the DE? Does this information live in a data view or somewhere we can query it into a data extension?

Thanks in advance!

Nikki

Answer (score 2):

There are no publicly available dataviews that I've found.

Aside from doing the data extract > import your mention, your alternative would be a custom report from Salesforce

Answer (score 0):

In latest releases an option to export customers to data extension from Web & Mobile Analytics Interface was added. See [this link](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/release_notes/october_2017_release/analytics_builder/)